# How to append text to selected item in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-select2

I'm trying to edit the selected value of a select2. So I did this simple code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcky9/2/

**HTML**

```
<select id="sel" style="width: 100%">
    <option value="1">Hello</option>
    <option value="2">Friends</option>
    <option value="3">Stackoverflow</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button id="addok">Add OK</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#sel").select2();

    $("#addok").click(function() {
        actual_value = $("#sel").find(':selected').text();

        if (actual_value.indexOf(" OK") > -1){
            return
        }

        newtext = actual_value + " OK";

        // this works.
        $("#sel").find(':selected').text(newtext);

        // this does not works.
        $('#s2id_sel').find('.select2-choosen').text(newtext);
    });
});
```

As you see, after pressing the button, looks like nothing had changed, but if you open the dropdown, the `OK` was added successfully at the current item.

The problem appears when I try to modify the actual value located in a div with `select2-choosen` css class. I can't access it by this way.

Do you have any idea, advice or tip to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firing the `change()` on select will show the appended ok, you need to trigger `change()` There is no element with id `s2id_sel` and class `.select2-choosen` to last statement wont change the text.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rcky9/3/)**

```
$("#sel").find(':selected').text(newtext).change();
```

Comment: And you know how do the same using an icon font? http://jsfiddle.net/rcky9/8/ Your method does not work in this case. Thanks. :)